# Logrotate - keep file for two days

Tags: logging, logrotate

Is there any possibility to configure logrotate so it will keep file for 2 days instead of 1?

e.g. this configuration

```
copytruncate
daily
compress
dateext
missingok
```

leads to compressing file every day. However if logrotate is running at 1:00 am and there is a process that runs from 00:00 to 03:00 am, then its log is splitted into two files. What I would like to achive is to keep the log in one file but still compress old logs and delete older than 7 days.

I use ubuntu 14.04 and logrotate 3.8.7

Comment: Add name of Linux distribution and version to your question.

Comment: Is this really distribution dependent?

Comment: Yes, if you want to change the time when logrotate runs.

Answer (score 0):

If a rotation interval is not specified the log will be rotated whenever you call logrotate. So you can create a cron that calls logrotate with a configuration file which runs every 2 days. The configuration file will have other settings like compression, log file location etc.

The cron will look like

```
logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.conf
```